# A VideoPlayerController was used after being disposed. Once you have called dispose() on a VideoPlayerController, it can no longer be used

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: screenshot]

I am using [chewie](https://github.com/brianegan/chewie) player to play a list of videos in pageview.builder. when i scroll my page below it works fine,but when i scroll my page to view top video it shows me this error.How can i re-initialize the videoplayercontroller.

Comment: How did you solve? Could you share your implementation of page view builder with Chewie Video? Thanks!

Comment: Please someone give the answer I am also getting same issue

Answer (score 4):

problem is you have to destroy the container that is using the video player and setting .dipose() after its destroyed. So your kill function should be something like this:

```
void killVidPlayer() {
    yourContainer = Container();
    setState(() {

    });

    _controller.dispose();
    _controller = null;
}
```

Comment: Well done Adrian, yes we should remove the widget or change it if we are going to dispose the player.

Comment: I was missing the _controller=null piece; worked after that for me.

Comment: _controller.dispose(); does not clear the instance in the memory and then set it to null automatically?

Comment: @Manas back when i posted this, it was a hit or miss. I guess it was a race condition.

Answer (score 2):

So i followed what this guy said here and it worked [github](https://github.com/brianegan/chewie/issues/170#issuecomment-509108742)

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();  //Super should be called at the very beginning of init
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
      'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4',
    );
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _controller,
      aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
    );
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose(); //Super should be called at the very end of dispose
  }

//Let me know if this doesn't solve your issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me.

```
@override
void dispose() {
  // It is necessary to pause before dispose, otherwise an error will occur during dispose
  // [Once you have called dispose() on a YoutubePlayerController, it can no longer be used.]
  _youtubeController?.pause();

  // After playback stops, dispose
  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 40)).then((value) => _youtubeController?.dispose());

  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).